# how to ignore subject field or define a default value for it,in a Microsoft dynamic crm Activity form

Tags: dynamics-crm

I create a new Activity in Microsoft dynamic CRM for sending SMS. but i dont need the "Subject" field in Activity Form and want to ignore it.

I tried to hide the subject field but is require field.

first i deselect the visible by default option in field property. after publish the customization i open the form and subject field has been hide. but when i pressed the Save button, activity form alert me You must provide a value for Subject. and show subject field.

how can i ignore Subject or define a default value for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the requirement level.
On the form designer double click on the field. This will show you the Field Properties where the `Visible by default` checkbox is.

Click on the `Details` tab and then click the `Edit` button.

Here you can set the Requirement Level from `Business Required` to `No Constraint`.

Now you can hide the field from your form.

Save and Publish your customizations.

Your other option is using JavaScript.

On Load of the form you could use the following:

```js
// Change the required level
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").setRequiredLevel("none");
```

On Save you could use the following:

```js
// Set a default value
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").setValue("This is your default value");
```

Comment: I made some corrections to your answer, after you change the requirement level the field can be set not visible, but still cannot be removed from the form. Changing the requirement works, but I suggest to still set a value, `subject` is a particular field for activity entity types, and to have empty values can lead to potential issues. +1